# Use entire Json object as string variable

Tags: jmeter

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to create variables off of json strings.

For instance, in my API request I have this part:

```
"deliveryAddress": {
      "name": "string",
      "address": "string",
      "address2": "string",
      "address3": "string",
      "zip": "52145",
      "city": "Falköping",
      "countryCode": "SE"
    }
```

Instead of creating seven variables, I want to create ONE variable that contains everything in deilveryAddress and just read them from a random set of multiple deliveryAddress.

Easiest way to do this?

Thansk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('deliveryAddress', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).deliveryAddress).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. That's it, now you should have `${deliveryAddress}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding these 7 (or whatever number it will be in the response) child records

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)